# Using methods across all activities in android

Tags: java, android, static, instance

I know there are already some questions on global methods and variables in android but I'm running into problems with static methods probably due to my less experience with objectoriented programming. So here is what I want to have:

I am writing an app which counts points which the user can earn for certain things he does. Because of that I want to call the method `addPoints` from different activities and services. This method should also set the points textview in the main activity and some other things.

I realized it by adding a static variable

```
static int sPoints;
```

in the MainActivity, that I use as a "global" variable in each activity.
However, with the `addPoints` method I have some problems. If I use a non-static method, I have to create an instance of MainActivity in the other activities, which is not very nice and changing the values of that instance does not have an effect on the actual MainActivity.

If I use a static function it works fine as long as I don't want to use non-static methods like in this example:

```
public static void addPoints(Context context, int points){
    int levelBefore, levelAfter;

    levelBefore = getLevelFromPoints(sPoints);
    sPoints = sPoints + points;
    levelAfter = getLevelFromPoints(sPoints);

    if(levelBefore!=levelAfter){
        String rank = getRankFromLevel(levelAfter);
        levelTextView.setText("Lvl. " + String.valueOf(levelAfter));
        Toast.makeText(context, "Congrats! You reached the next level!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Here I can't easily use levelTextView.setText and I run into this problem in many other cases. Moreover, I've read that using static methods is not good, anyway.

So would the correct way be creating an instance of MainActivity each time and then call `addPoints` on it which has to return the new number of points? Or is there another way (I hope so, because both above ways seem to be not very satisfying).

Comment: I see a parameter `Context context` being passed and i am pretty sure that you dont know that it is the instance of the main activity which is already running. just create an interface and call it to update the textviews

Comment: You could try putting the value in a shared preference and query it whenever needed. Android does all the dirty work in the background and its not very expensive.

Comment: hi friend you can use dagger. Here is example of public methods and i'm  not make it static see https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sampleapp/utils/AppUtils.java

Answer (score 0):

a. Static methods can safely be used in case your work can not be accomplished by `ShardPreferences` and requires the use of same code at multiple classes like in your case.
b. First create an interface that will pass the updated rank to respective activities or classes

```
public interface ScoreUpdater {
    void updateScore (String rank);
}
```

c. then implement it in all activities where required to use, MainActivity in this case

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ScoreUpdater{
     //
    //other methods and codes
   //
    @Override
    public void updateScore(String rank) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                levelTextView.setText("Lvl. " + String.valueOf(levelAfter));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Congrats! You reached the next level!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

d. then implement your static methods. not sure where you have declared few variables. so my method below is on guess work.

```
public static void addPoints(Context context, int points){
        //not sure where you are declaring sPoints
        int levelBefore, levelAfter;
        levelBefore = getLevelFromPoints(sPoints);
        sPoints = sPoints + points;
        levelAfter = getLevelFromPoints(sPoints);

        if(levelBefore!=levelAfter){
            String rank = getRankFromLevel(levelAfter);
            if(context instanceof ScoreUpdater){
                ((ScoreUpdater)context).updateScore(rank);
            }
        }
    }

    private static int getLevelFromPoints(int points){
        //your operations
        return points;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Is there also a way to change the textViews of the running MainActivity if addPoints is called from a notification?

Comment: notifications run on service, and communication between service and activity is done through broadcast receivers. as far as i know, calling interfaces from service is not safe. so go through broadcast receivers, might help